# Force pdfjam to fit a specific size in final output

Tags: pdf, printing, pdftk

My intentions is to make a full book cover (a wide page including the book’s back, the spine, and the front cover).

To achieve this, I have three PDF files containing the front page (`first-page.pdf` A4 size), the last page (`last-page.pdf` A4 size) and the spine (`spine.pdf` with 2cm width) like this:

[image: Project’s PDF files]

So, the goal is to make fusion between this tree files to make one single file like this:

[image: Expected rendering]

In order to get the expected rendering, I try pdfjam with the following options:

`pdfjam --nup 3x1 --papersize '{440mm,297mm}' last-page.pdf spine.pdf first-page.pdf -o output.pdf`

But the output didn’t fit my expectations:

[image: Real result]

Since I add `--papersize '{440mm,297mm}'` I thank pdfjam will be forced to fit this size, however it still process the spine file as a full A4 sized and dind’t care about the real size of this file nor the size I explicitly give in the input.

So, how to force pdfjam to add the spine file without adding unwanted padding?

BTW, any solution to make fusion of this tree files, also with other tools than pdfjam, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The pdfjam utility is a wrapper around the LaTeX [pdfpages package](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf); you might want to read its documentation.

You can reduce the spacing between pages by setting the `delta` property to something negative. (Here you want the first number for `delta` to be negative to reduce horizontal spacing.)

```
pdfjam --nup 3x1 --papersize '{440mm,297mm}' --delta '{-95mm 0mm}' last-page.pdf spine.pdf first-page.pdf -o output.pdf
```

[image: spine example]

I think -95mm works out because A4 paper is usually 210mm wide; your spine is 20mm, leaving a 190mm gap to be reduced evenly on each side by 95mm. But it's possible you may need to tweak the exact value.

There might be a better way, however, as I haven't explored every possibility with the package.